# Button too high in h2

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

This is my code (please see the fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/deZet/)):

```
<h2>Icecream<a href='#' class='btn pull-right'><i class='icon-star'></i> Follow</a></h2>
```

The problem (as seen by the red background), is that the `pull-right` button is too high. How can I get the button to be at the same height as the `h2`?

Comment: What have you tried?  Adding a top margin to the btn would likely fix this.

Comment: Do you mean centered within the `<h2>`? I'm assuming you don't want to use `margin-top`?

Comment: Yes, `margin-top` is an awful hack.

Comment: When it comes to vertical alignment in CSS it's usually the least awful hack.

Comment: Are you opposed to adding a wrapper around your follow button?

Comment: The undesirable vertical alignment is caused by the fact that your anchor tag is floated right.

Comment: @Jrod: Nope, that would be a more semantic way of doing things.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/deZet/21/ Depending on how your actual project is you may need to tweak the line-height value and or units.

Comment: @Jrod Divs aren't allowed inside h2 tags.

Comment: @cimmanon span would also work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what you mean, but I added this to the css block and it pushed the button down to the center of the H1 if that helps:

```
.pull-right {
    margin-top: 5px;
}
```

I would recommend keeping your h1 and your button separate within a div. Best to keep the alignment of elements separate where possible.

Comment: `margin-top` is a horrible hack.

Comment: Quick and dirty but it works for the cdoe that was presented. What would you recommend @Randomblue?

Comment: @ZincX It "works" until the font-size changes.  Plenty of users override the font-size of their browser to something larger.

Answer (score -1):

```
.btn.pull-right {
    position:relative;
    top:5px;
}
```

Comment: It's just as awful as applying margin-top.

Comment: The OP never said "I prefer not to use the following". The OP asked "how do I do this?" A valid answer is a valid answer.

Comment: @cimmanon can you show one instance where this does not work?

Comment: As I stated in another comment, if the font-size changes, it no longer works.  Some users *do* adjust their font-size and there's nothing you can do about it.

Comment: @cimmanon Have you read the css file being mentioned in the jsfiddle example (twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css)? Font-size will have no effect for the code being presented...even test for yourself.

Comment: I don't need to look at the referenced CSS because the order of specificity is as follows:  user defined > author > browser default.  If I tell my browser that my absolute minimum font-size is 20px, then it will be 20px.  http://jsfiddle.net/deZet/32/

Comment: @cimmanon using `* { font-size: 50px !important }` is **HARDLY** a realistic scenario. Also you should look at the referenced CSS, which explains why you have to use `!important`.  If you take that out, my solution still works... http://jsfiddle.net/dirtyd77/deZet/33/ . You are now altering the entire stylesheet which goes beyond your initial comment. All I'm saying is give credit where credit is due, not downvote because **you're** not a fan of the solution.

Comment: Did you just skim over the part where I specifically mention user style sheets or taking advantage of the minimum font-size in my browser?  I can't very well include my browser settings in a fiddle for you.  Bad answers deserve down votes just as much as wrong answers do.

Answer (score -2):

If you're in a situation where you can't modify the markup, flexbox can do this.  I've included prefixes for all of the browsers that should be able to do this (FF versions following the 2009 spec can't do this because they don't insert anonymous flex item boxes around text).  You're free to keep the float there for browsers who can't do flexbox.

http://jsfiddle.net/deZet/31/

```
h2 {
  background-color: red;
  display: -webkit-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-pack: justify;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  justify-content: space-between;
  -webkit-flex-align: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  align-items: center;
}

h2 a.btn.pull-right {
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 auto;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox

If you're open to modifying the markup, using table/table-cell also works, but you'll need to get rid of the float.

http://jsfiddle.net/deZet/34/

```
h2 {
    background-color: red;
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
}

h2 .cell {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

h2 .cell:last-child {
    text-align: right;
    line-height: 1;
}

<h2><span class="cell">Icecream</span> <span class="cell"><a href='#' class='btn'><i class='icon-star'></i> Follow</a></span></h2>
```